# Какой вариант реализации метода приоритетнее?

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность

Есть некий клиент, под капотом у которого `HttpClient`

```
public class Client
{
    private HttpClient httpClient;

    private const string BaseAddress = "https://api.domain.com/";

    public Client(string clientId, string password)
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress) };
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue
        (
            "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", clientId, password)))
        );
    }

    protected async Task<T> JsonGetAsync<T>(string requestUrl, params object[] values)
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(string.Format(requestUrl, values)).ConfigureAwait(false);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json));
    }

    //обычная реализация
    public List<Sport> GetSports() => JsonGetAsync<SportsResponse>("v2/sports").Result.Sports;

    //Task реализация 
    public Task<SportsResponse> GetSports() => JsonGetAsync<SportsResponse>("v2/sports");
}
```

Какая реализация метода `GetSports` будет самой оптимальной с точки зрения производительности?

Comment: Определите критерий оптимальности, что значит "самой оптимальной"?

Comment: @tym32167 я немножко не правильно изначально описал сам пример. По сути я имел ввиду что лучше возвращать саму задачу или объект, так как есть прорехи в понимании асинхронного кода.

Comment: Вам видимо нужно создать новый вопрос и там предельно ясно описать что вас интересует с минимальным примером кода.